# Make a div tag toggle between two css classes

Tags: javascript, toggle, hide, show

What i want to do is to change the class of the div tag with a toggle button using javascript.
So that when i press the button once the div tag gets the show class, and when i press the same button again it gets the hide class. Is this possible?

html:

```
<a id="togglebutton">Show/hide</a>

<div class="show"> 
   I want this div to toggle between the 'show' class and the 'hide' class
</div>
```

css:

```
.show {
    display: block;
}


.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
function toggle(){
    var hide = document.querySelector(".hide");
    var show = document.querySelector(".show");

}

var hidebutton = document.querySelector(".togglebutton");
hidebutton.onclick = toggle
```

Would `document.getElementById("MyId").className = "MyClass";` be usable somehow?

Comment: #togglebutton not .togglebutton which is a class not an ID

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
if(document.getElementById("MyId").className == "hide")
   document.getElementById("MyId").className = "show";
else
   document.getElementById("MyId").className = "hide";
```

But you need first to give an ID to the div..
Please find below a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HvmmY/

Comment: This is old, but saved me. Thank you for the simple and beautiful answer! Also, the example was amazing!

Comment: You don't need to remove the existing class first?

Comment: @Jarad it's used under the assumption that only one class needs to be present at time. Writing to `className` overwrites any other class that was present there, thus becoming a 'toggle'

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to show / hide an element, you can use the style.display property :

```
hidebutton.onclick = function(){
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('show').item(0);
    if(div.style.display == '') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to toggle the hide class

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("togglebutton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
    var show = this.innerHTML == "Show";
    document.getElementById(this.dataset.id).classList.toggle("hide",!show)
    this.innerHTML = show ? "Hide" : "Show";
  })
})
```

```css
.hide { display:none;}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="togglebutton" data-id="toggleDiv">Hide</a>

<div id="toggleDiv" class="show">
  I want this div to toggle between the 'show' class and the 'hide' class
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution (I voted it up). Could be even better if it got the id of the element as it was clicked, because there may be multiple divs to toggle.

Comment: @jxwd 7 year old solution. I updated it to 2021

Answer (score -2):

I like to use jquery for adding/removing `<div>` classes. However, it might not work in your situation.

You might be able to use jQuery on it with `toggle`:

`$('#box').click(function() {

  $('#box2').toggleClass('show hide');

  });`

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mFA5F/1/

Information on `toggle()` can be seen here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/